# Creating relations with collections in Meteor

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Perhaps this structure is not a good fit for Meteor, or maybe I'm thinking about it wrong.
Is trying to do a relation like this bad in a noSQL db?

I have Dropzone and Widget collections. A Dropzone can have many widgets, and each widget can exist in more than one dropzone.

My problem is that I can't seem to make Handlebars render the filtered list of widgets.

My dropzone model

```
dropzone =
  _id: "area1-id"
  title: "Area 1"
```

Widget model (abbreviated)

```
widget =
  _id: "widget1-id"
  title: "My Widget"
  dropzones: ['area1-id', 'area2-id'] 
  # each widget stores an id of which dropzones it's associated with
```

Relevant template structure

```
{{#each dropzones}}
  <div class="dropzone span4">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="widget-area">
      <div class="hotzone">
        {{#widgets _id}} # passing in the current dropzone id
        {{/widgets}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Helper Function

```
# returns the correct sets of widgets, but can't figure
# out how to make it render the widget partial
Handlebars.registerHelper 'widgets', (drop_id)->
  widgets = CC.Widgets.find(dropzones: drop_id)
  _.each widgets, (widget)->
    Template.widget(widget)  # this ends up being blank with no error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want looks a little more like this:

```
  <div class="hotzone">
    {{#each widgets}}
      {{> widget}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

Helper:

```
Template.foo.widgets = -> CC.Widgets.find(dropzones: this._id)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Awesome, that worked!
For whatever reason, I couldn't wrap my head around the value of this as the template was being evaluated. Turns out I was making it more complicated then necessary.

Comment: Yeah, it takes some getting used to, but it can be really awesome.